# What are potential consequences of importing pre-existing Canvas Power App and Power Automate Flows to a new Solution?

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-canvas, power-platform, dataverse

We have a Canvas Power App which connects to a SharePoint Data Source.  We also have multiple Power Automate Flows that manipulate this same data after certain triggers (when created, when updated, etc).  None of these components are in a Power Apps solution.

After reading about the benefits of Solutions in the Power Platform, my question is this:

If I was to create a new Power Apps Solution and then import both the pre-existing Canvas App and the Power Automate Flows, can I expect the solution to continue to function correctly?

What potential issues might I run into?

For context, both the Canvas app and the workflows are used daily by staff.

Answer (score 0):

ALM improvements are really good these days wrt Power Platform, especially for Canvas apps and PA Cloud flows. They are continuously improving as well.

Notable improvements are Connections, Connection references, Environmental variables and the Solutions can include the Flows, Canvas apps like any other Dataverse/Dynamics CRM components.

Definitely some will break after deployment in target environment and it really depends on your customizations and development strategies. I’m not sure how this was deployed in target environment in first place, they were exported and imported as packages probably.

So I recommend you to dry run / test the deployment thoroughly using solution from source to another target sandbox environment before doing deployment to real Prod environment with users actively using them.